# How do I get my object's metadata information in Binary format in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I am recieving binary stream from an application I am running in Python.

From the binary stream, I want to create a C# object that is inside the stream in byte array.

How do I deserialise the object and retrieve the object from the binary stream?

We can ignore that it's a python application.  I am more interested in how binary streaming works.

Comment: *"We can ignore that it's a python application."* -> Removed the `python` tag. :-)

Comment: What do you mean, "how binary streaming works"? You write bytes to the stream, and read them back later.

Comment: And why is this tagged Java, anyway?

Comment: when i read it, how do i get metadata information of the object that is serialised in the binary stream?

Comment: because this concept applies in all of the languages that can serialise and deserialise binary streams

Comment: But you asked how to create a C# object ... which you obviously can't do in Java.  This is not a Java question.

Comment: I don't think we always close questions on SO just because the premise is unfounded...

Comment: Who said anything about closing the question?  We are just talking about getting rid of inappropriate tags ...

Comment: @StephenC Whoever cast the close vote - I couldn't target the comment at anyone in particular so just wrote a general one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add you a little general info:

In C#/.Net there's a general approach to serialize objects to NOT a binary form, because a binary form needs a lot of protocol-like headers to - note - include the metadata, and this causes the receiver to have to know the .Net/CLR inner structure very well.

Instead, today, the objects are usually serialized to XML (when type information is crucial) or JSON formats (when only data matters), so that any receiver may read them quite easily, and more often - any 3rd party may easily generate new object-like data that our application may "just deserialize", regardless of who generated it and on what platform.

However, binary serialization is still used. XML/JSON data, even if compressed, is still usually larger than the binary image. However, the binary serialization is strictly used when we **want** the data to **not be published** to the outside world, or if we somehow magically know that it will be only processed on .Net with use of **our assemblies**.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to think that all languages automatically use the same serialization scheme.

- This is not so.
- It is not even theoretically possible, because different programming languages have different notions of what it means to be an object.

If you are specifically interested in how to read a Python serialized stream in C#, then ask that.  Otherwise, this question is unanswerable because it is based on a false premise.

---

**FOLLOW UP** - Out of curiosity, I did some searching for a Python pickle reader in C#.  Nothing in the first 3 pages of search results ... though there was a reference to a pickle reader in C++.

Answer (score 0):

> C# object

C# does not have objects; it's a .Net object.

Secondly we absolutely CANNOT ignore that it's a Python application, because that implies that it's likely it's not running on .Net and therefore the .Net binary format is not native to your Python runtime.  That's not to say that it's not *possible* for the .Net serialization to be available to you in this case, because if you're running [IronPython - the .Net python implementation](http://ironpython.net/) - then you can simply use the Binary serialization APIs from within that and get the *.Net object* that was serialized.

If, however, it's Python running on a different platform, then you can decode the information in the binary stream, for that you need to know the format, and for that go straight to the horse's mouth and read through the [Binary Format Data Structure spec from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236844%28PROT.10%29.aspx).

This will, of course, require (quite a lot) more work!

If the project you're working on allows you to change the way that the original object is serialized, then I strongly suggest changing over to XML serialization or something similar - that is designed to be portable.